# Date date = calendar.getTime() returning date in the past

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get notifications to send in my Android app. I want to send a different notification every week on certain days of the week.

I've got code written that successfully creates the notification using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver. The problem I'm facing is that the notifications are running as soon as the app runs. I've discovered that this is because I'm passing values to the following code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayofweek);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourofday);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dayminute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, daysecond);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

For example, let's say today is Wednesday, July25. If I pass a 1 for dayofweek, Calendar.Day_OF_WEEK is set to Sunday. The problem is when I do calendar.getTime(), the date is set at Sunday, July 22, in the past and not the next Sunday as I would expect (which would be July 29). So what's happening is the alarm manager is scheduling my notification in the past. Since I'm using alarmManager.setRepeating the notification is going to fire immediately, according to the [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) which states:

> "If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be
>   triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the
>   past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval."

My question is this: how do I prevent calendar.getTime() from returning a date in the past and return a future date instead?

Comment: Don't use `Calender` use the "new" `java.time` API (it's already 4 years old)

Comment: Use `Calendar.add()` instead of `Calendar.set()`. `add()` will correctly roll over to the other fields. The same is true for the new time API (`withDayOfWeek()` vs. `plus()`).

Comment: If your target API Level permits it, the recommended approach would indeed be to look into the java.time API and e.g. [LocalDateTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime)

Comment: @MalteHartwig this should be an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Calendar.add()` method will make sure that the other fields (like DAY_OF_MONTH, MONTH, and so on) roll over properly. You just have to convert from your fixed `dayOfWeek` value to the difference betwenn today and that day:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, (dayOfWeek - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7) % 7);
```

Note that this does not respect the time, i.e. when you give it the weekday of today, but a time in the past, the result will still be in the past. To make sure that the result is always in the future, put in a check after setting the values:

```
public static Calendar getClosestFutureWeekday(int dayOfWeek, int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
    }
    return calendar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Date class to set the dates. Here are examples of getting the date a week from now and a week ago.

Using **cal.add();** will add the days onto the calendar instead of using **cal.set();**

A week from today:

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(today);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
```

A week ago:

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(today);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the date after it is produced and if it is in the past add 7 days to it:

```
    Long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentDateTime);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayofweek);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourofday);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dayminute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, daysecond);

    if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < currentDateTime) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
    }

    Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can move on from obsolete java.util.Calendar to Java 8 java.time.* classes, please do yourself a favor and do so. I'm assuming Android means you can't.

The reason why setting the calendar to Sunday doesn't advance the date as you thought but instead goes back in time, is because of **first day of week** conventions. Not all cultures think that Monday is the first day of the week. Some believe Sunday is. Others take other days too.

For your calendar to behave exactly as you want it to, you must define to it what is the first day of week in your own convention, rather than let it decide on its own.

So, before you do anything else,

```
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Then, everything else in your program is correct.